# Can't compare std::list iterator to list::back()?

Tags: c++, templates, stl

I have a custom iterator template class that wraps up a `std::list` iterator. In my `hasNext()` method I want to check to see if the iterator refers to the last item in the list. However this code:

```
template< class Type >
...
virtual bool hasNext( void )
{
    return itTypes != pList->back();
}
...
typename std::list< Type > * pList;
typename std::list< Type >::iterator itTypes;
```

Produces the error:

`error C2678: binary '!=' : no operator found which takes a left-hand operand of type 'std::_List_iterator<_Mylist>'`

If I compare `itTypes` to `list::begin()` or `list::end()` I get no problem. The documentation I've looked at for STL iterators says that the bidirectional iterators used by std::list support the equality and inequality comparison operators. Is there a reason I can't compare to `list::back()` then?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You want `end()`. `back()` gets the *value* of the last element, which is not an iterator into the list at all.

Comment: Why are the most annoying bugs always the simplest :/ Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 1):

the back() return the element not the iterator.
so use code

```
return *itTypes != pList->back()
```

Answer (score 1):

The `begin()` and `end()` function return iterator while `front()` and `back()` return element reference